# Block Win RT Uri Association

Tags: c#, webview, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a problem where my WebView is trying to navigate to a URL like "myapp:///mobilesdk/". When it does this, the OS tries to launch an app from the store, when really I want the NavigationStarting event to be fired, and i can cancel the navigation and do what I want.

Is there a way for me to stop the OS from from trying to launch an app?

Just to add I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 in the WinRT, not silverlight.

Comment: Let me understand. You have App1 that uses Protocol1. You have a WebView in App1 that calls Protocol1. The WebView looks to the Store and does not call App1's Protocol1, though? Is that the problem?

Comment: No my app uses no protocol. I want to supress the protocol behaviour that the app uses, because i want to do some stuff in code behind.

Comment: Why are you against registering a protocol, though? If the concern is that the app's state will be lost, I believe there's a way to prevent that.

Comment: Its just not the behaviour i want. The webview is trying to navigate to a page that fires off this protocol behaviour, and i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Windows 8 implements custom protocols is such that when you call `anything:`, it first looks to local associations (which includes desktop applications). If none is found, it then prompts the user with a dialog to search the Windows Store. There is no way to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Jerry is correct with how protocols are implemented.  For this scenario I can see how you'd not expect the behavior of exposing the url to the System launcher.  There is not a first class event to help you on the WebView today.

A potential way to work around this would be to utilize invokeScriptAsync, and the ScriptNotify events.

```
myWebView.DOMContentLoaded += myWebView_DOMContentLoaded;
myWebView.ScriptNotify += myWebView_ScriptNotify;

void myWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: handle e.Value
}

async void myWebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    await mwv.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.body.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(e) {if (e.srcElement.tagName == 'A') {e.preventDefault();try {window.external.notify(e.srcElement.href);}catch(err){console.log('ERROR: window.external.notify does not exist');}}}, true)" });
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This code is injecting this function into the WebView content when the DOM is loaded:

```
function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.srcElement.tagName == 'A') {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            window.external.notify(e.srcElement.href);
        }catch(err){
            console.log("ERROR: window.external.notify doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

This might not be the desired approach depending on your content as this function would block all of the A tags from navigating outside of the code in your parent applications myWebView_ScriptNotify function.  You'd have to have all your logic for handling the A tags navigations there.  This might be what you are looking for but if you have an href='http://www.somewhere.com' this would go through that mechanism too.